# Embedding videos in beamer LaTeX

Tags: beamer, multimedia, video

I followed slavishly the code shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_N1A1yX0xg) video:

```
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{frame}{Name-of-the-frame}
    \centering
    \movie[externalviewer]{
\includegraphics[width=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{auxiliary-image.jpg}
}{video_to_be_added.mp4}
\end{frame}
```

The PDF compiled but when I click (or `Ctrl`+click) on `auxiliary-image.jpg`, nothing happens. Why? I am compiling the document on Overleaf if that is relevant.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Right... uhm, I've always let Edge open PDFs.

Comment: Maybe you find a windows user who knows if there are any viewers which work with multimedia.

Comment: I just tried Adobe, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hello there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. I'm not sure if I could help, but please bear in mind that the Overleaf's own PDF viewer won't support the media for sure. That's just in case you tried that and it's what you ask about. (It wasn't clear to me from your question.) You need to download the PDF and use a local PDF viewer. You could also try to switch to the browser's PDF viewer in Overleaf's Menu, but I would be surprised if that helped TBH...